# How to execute .asm files on Apple Silicon?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, arm64, apple-silicon

I'm interested in writing and understanding assembly. I'm currently trying on a M2 Apple chip. And I just want to translate x86-64 assembly code to ARM64 one. Is it possible ? And how?

To do so i started to write some code in nasm (i found the most documentation on it but feel free to give me advice if you have a better understanding of the subject), and when i want to execute the .o file that the command : `nasm -f elf64 -l hello.lst hello.asm` gave me I have an error.

Of course it is because my processor is an M2 chip from Apple, but I couldn't figure out how I can (if I can) change those x86-64 executable files to files my computer can understand.

After some research I could not find gcc or nasm commands to make those files. I am also aware of Apple's Rosetta but I couldn't put it in use also.

Also, should I keep trying writing in nasm assembly, or may I start to learn ARM64 assembly?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Use an emulator, like QEMU.

Comment: If you have an x86-64 assembly program meant to run on macOS, you should be able to build an object file and link it into an x86-64 binary, which you can then run with Rosetta.  However, it looks like you have found a tutorial for Linux, not macOS.  So it can't work in any case.

Comment: ARM64 aka AArch64 is a fairly clean ISA that I think has less quirky weird stuff than x86-64.  It has its share of complexity like using `stp` / `ldp` (load-pair / store-pair) as push/pop to keep the stack 16-byte aligned at all times, not just when making function calls.  If you're interested in Macs, native code on them is going to be AArch64 for the foreseeable future, and it's a mainstream ISA that's it could be useful to be familiar with.  (Learning other ISAs later is much easier once you understand basic asm concepts from learning asm on one ISA.)

Comment: NASM is a nice assembler with good usually-meaningful error messages that tend to be helpful to humans, unlike GNU assembler which sometimes has error messages that are basically wrong, so you have to know the ISA to look for yourself at the instruction it complained about and see what the actual problem is.  I don't know if GAS or clang for AArch64 are better in this respect than GAS for x86-64.  (GAS error messages are often helpful for x86-64, but not always.)  Anyway, looking for an ARM64 MacOS assembly tutorial is totally reasonable and a good way to start.